# How to trigger ignite checkpoint before shutdown?

Tags: java, ignite

I have an embedded Ignite instance in my java-application.

When I shutdown my application Ignite is closed correctly:

```
@PreDestroy
public void preDestroy() {
    log.info("Ignite Destroying...");
    ignite.close();
}
```

I expect that during "Ignite.close" operation all wal-files are being flushed. But that doesn't happen, and when I start my application I see the following:

```
Applying lost cache updates since last checkpoint record [lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=255, fileOff=52006828, len=99257], lastCheckpointId=ff637138-fb4f-4012-bce6-1728e6bf5162]
```

And I have to wait that operation to finish.

How to trigger wal checkpoint manually before application shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ignition.stop(false)` to avoid stopping current checkpoint.

Unfortunately, the only way to *force* checkpoint is to deactivate your cluster.

See [`--deactivate`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology#section-cluster-activation-tool) `control.sh` command. You can also do it [with code](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCluster.html#active-boolean-).

**UPD:** I think that another way to force a checkpoint is enabling WAL on a cache where it was disabled previously, handy for data ingestion workflow.

Comment: Thank you! And how can I deactivate the cluster?